# Need a function that parse out data from two nested objects in an array using lodash and pass it as a prop in a react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props

I have a react components that needs to dynamically preload some values from a couple of arrays in the background from a couple of nested objects in 1 array of data.

```
import React, {
  useEffect
} from "react";

export function layoutComponent({
  config,
  LayoutRenderer
}) {
  const loadModules = (name) => queryModule(name);
  useEffect(() => {
    const modules = parseModules(config);
    modules.forEach(module => loadModules(module));
  }, [])


  return ( <
    LayoutRenderer config = {
      modules
    }
    />
  )
}

layoutComponent.propTypes = {
  LayoutRenderer: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  config: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
}
```

I need to take the `parseModules` and create a function that parse through the array of  objects below called `config`.  I need to get the `name` value from `config.header.customizableArea.slots.modules.name` and I need to also get `overview.slots.modules.name`

```
config =  [{
  "name": "Default",
  "description": "This is the default layout configuration.",
  "userGroup": "gg-servicing-wings-ccp",
  "header": {
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "ucidEnabled": true,
    "journeySearchEnabled": true,
    "customizableArea": {
      "className": "",
      "height": "",
      "slots": [{
          "slotId": "00",
          "layout": "",
          "visibleModule": "servicing-card-art",
          "className": "dls-white-bg",
          "size": {
            "sm": {
              "rowSpan": "1",
              "colSpan": "6"
            },
            "md": {
              "rowSpan": "1",
              "colSpan": "6"
            },
            "lg": {
              "rowSpan": "1",
              "colSpan": "6"
            }
          },
          "modules": [{
            "name": "servicing-card-art",
            "props": ["accountToken", "accountToken:accountTokenToDisplay"]
          }]
        },
        {
          "slotId": "01",
          "layout": "",
          "visibleModule": "servicing-card-art",
          "className": "dls-white-bg",
          "size": {
            "sm": {
              "rowSpan": "1",
              "colSpan": "6"
            },
            "md": {
              "rowSpan": "1",
              "colSpan": "6"
            },
            "lg": {
              "rowSpan": "1",
              "colSpan": "6"
            }
          },
          "modules": [{
            "name": "servicing-card-art",
            "props": ["accountToken", "accountToken:accountTokenToDisplay"]
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "overview": {
    "className": "",
    "height": "",
    "slots": [{
        "slotId": "00",
        "layout": "",
        "visibleModule": "servicing-card-art",
        "className": "dls-white-bg",
        "size": {
          "sm": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          },
          "md": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          },
          "lg": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          }
        },
        "modules": [{
          "name": "servicing-card-art",
          "props": ["accountToken", "accountToken:accountTokenToDisplay"]
        }]
      },
      {
        "slotId": "01",
        "layout": "",
        "visibleModule": "servicing-card-art",
        "className": "dls-white-bg",
        "size": {
          "sm": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          },
          "md": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          },
          "lg": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          }
        },
        "modules": [{
          "name": "servicing-card-art",
          "props": ["accountToken", "accountToken:accountTokenToDisplay"]
        }]
      },
      {
        "slotId": "02",
        "layout": "",
        "visibleModule": "servicing-card-art",
        "className": "dls-white-bg",
        "size": {
          "sm": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          },
          "md": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          },
          "lg": {
            "rowSpan": "1",
            "colSpan": "2"
          }
        },
        "modules": [{
          "name": "servicing-card-art",
          "props": ["accountToken", "accountToken:accountTokenToDisplay"]
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  "autoLaunch": ["servicing-card-replacement"]
}]
```

Comment: so `config[0].header.customizableArea.slots[0].modules.name`?

Comment: @CharlesBamford yes and `config[0].overview.slots[0].modules.name`

Comment: @CharlesBamford is that clear?

Comment: It looks like you've got it? I don't understand what the problem is. You have 2.6k points, so I assume you've read the help center, but this isn't a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The below works for me to generate a list with the `name` fields from your sample data, although they are the same module name, so not sure if you needed something else there as well...

```js
const parseModules = (config) => {
  const modules = [];
  // Loop over objects in config.header
  config.forEach(conf => {
    conf.header.customizableArea.slots.forEach(slot => {
      slot.modules.forEach(module => modules.push(module.name))
    })
  });
  // Loop over objects in config.overview
  config.forEach(conf => {
    conf.overview.slots.forEach(slot => {
      slot.modules.forEach(module => modules.push(module.name))
    })
  });
  return modules;
}
const modules = parseModules(config);
```

Result: `["servicing-card-art", "servicing-card-art", "servicing-card-art", "servicing-card-art", "servicing-card-art"]`

Comment: But I also need to it for 'config[0].overview.slots[0].modules.name' and they need to be merged into one array `["servicing-card-art", "servicing-card-art"]`

Comment: Updated now, but again it is just generating a list of 5 identical strings since all these fields are identical.